# add Columns and reorder them

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

**first data frame :**

```
Index([ 'AvailabilityZone', 'CreateTime', 'Encrypted', 'Size',
       'SnapshotId', 'State', 'VolumeId', 'Iops', 'VolumeType',
       'MultiAttachEnabled', 'KmsKeyId', 'instanceId', 'name','Attachments']
      dtype='object')
```

**Second data frame :**

```
Index(['Attachments', 'AvailabilityZone', 'CreateTime', 'Size',
           'SnapshotId', 'VolumeId', 'Iops', 'Tags', 'VolumeType',
            'KmsKeyId', 'instanceId', 'name'],
          dtype='object')
```

I am calling API to pull data but i am getting columns in different order and sometimes columns are present and sometimes columns are not present

**Example :** In first data frame i have **'MultiAttachEnabled'** and **'State'** but i second dataframe we don't have those columns. I want to change the order columns as well  and remove some of the columns like **Tags** and **Encrypted**

In Final csv file i want to get  :

```
    Attachments,
    AvailabilityZone ,
    CreateTime,
    KmsKeyId,
    Size,
    SnapshotId,
    State,
    VolumeId,
    Iops,
    VolumeType,
    MultiAttachEnabled,
    instanceId,
    Throughput.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following where you add missing columns and order column name wise.

```
import numpy as np

# Required columns
columns = ['Attachments', 'AvailabilityZone', 'CreateTime', 'KmsKeyId', 'Size', 'SnapshotId', 'State', 'VolumeId', 'Iops', 'VolumeType', 'MultiAttachEnabled', 'instanceId', 'Throughput']

# Get missing columns
missing_columns = set(columns).difference(set(df.columns))

# Add missing columns
for i in missing_columns:
    df[i] = np.nan

# Reorder column
df = df.reindex(sorted(df.columns), axis=1)
```